# PHP convert byte string into integer

Tags: php, byte, unpack

I am trying to convert a 2 byte string into a Short/int data type with unpack but it does not seem to work:

```
$str = "\x01\xBB";
unpack("S",$str);
```

it gives **47873** where as it must return **443**

Comment: Why did you use `S` when your string seemingly requires big-endian unpacking?

Comment: S =  unsigned short (2 bytes)

Comment: S = (machine byte order).

Comment: Then what should be used instead?

Comment: `'n'` http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: Perfect! unpack("n",$str); give correct result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `n` as the format string instead.

```
$str = "\x01\xBB";
unpack("n",$str);
```

Look here for more format options.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php